# How do I apply score changes in SpamAssassin?

Tags: spamassassin

I'm trying to change a score of M`IME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY`, but whenever I change and restart spamassassin the score will not change.

I want to set the score to `0`, like:

```
score MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY 0.000 0.001 0.001 0.001

score MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY 0 # n=0 n=1 n=2 n=3
```

I have restarted spamassassin and postfix, but nothing, can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the changes should be placed in the `local.cf` config file:

```
score MIME_HEADER_CTYPE_ONLY 0.0
```

https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html#scoring_options